# Cannot use nested IF for CONCATENATE function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of data and need to use CONCATENATE to combine them as a string.

```
=CONCATENATE("{",char(34),0,char(34),":",B2,char(34),
IF(A3="Yes",CONCATENATE(",",char(34),1,char(34),":",B3),
IF(A4="Yes",CONCATENATE(",",char(34),2,char(34),":",B4),
IF(A5="Yes",CONCATENATE(",",char(34),1,char(34),":",B5),
IF(A6="Yes",CONCATENATE(",",char(34),1,char(34),":",B6))))),"}")
```

However, it only combines the first 2 data. Please help.

Demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-xZr2SC2t2E5QKtmTD1kQFr-K8GgJjIHL83Wqr6xYF8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
="{"&JOIN(",",FILTER(CHAR(34)&SEQUENCE(5,1,0)&CHAR(34)&":"&B2:B6,A2:A6="Yes"))&"}"
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But is it good for performance since I have to use this formula on 1000+ rounds

Comment: @JOY what is a "round"?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, rows, not rounds.

Comment: @JOY It should be fine. You will have to test of course